# Django syndication RSS feed_guid not working

Tags: python, django, rss, guid

Hopefully someone can help me on this. I have set up a basic RSS feed using the django syndication feed network. The basic feed works well, however by default django sets the GUID (unique identifier) as a link to the site. I would like the GUID to be the item.id.

I have used the following django example which works:

```
from django.contrib.syndication.views import Feed
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from policebeat.models import NewsItem

class LatestEntriesFeed(Feed):
    title = "Police beat site news"
    link = "/sitenews/"
    description = "Updates on changes and additions to police beat central."

    def items(self):
        return NewsItem.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

    def item_title(self, item):
        return item.title

    def item_description(self, item):
        return item.description
```

In the django docs it states as follows:

```
# GUID -- One of the following three is optional. The framework looks
# for them in this order. This property is only used for Atom feeds
# (where it is the feed-level ID element). If not provided, the feed
# link is used as the ID.

def feed_guid(self, obj):
    """
    Takes the object returned by get_object() and returns the globally
    unique ID for the feed as a normal Python string.
    """

def feed_guid(self):
    """
    Returns the feed's globally unique ID as a normal Python string.
```

But when I add the following to my code I get a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' error:

```
def feed_guid(self, item):
        return item.id
```

I am sure I has misunderstood this but can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of anyone else trying to use item.id as a guid. After looking through django code itself I found the answer to my problem.

Although the django docs state:

```
   def feed_guid(self, item):
        return item
```

I actually used the following which worked:

```
def item_guid(self, item)
        return item
```

The GUID of the rss feed is now the id of the item.